# Phonegap on Android. Can a lock screen orientation for a specific device size?

Tags: android, cordova, orientation

I am trying to lock the orientation for my Phonegap application on Android devices but only for small screens, ie telephones. On phones I would like to have only portrait but on tablet I would like both orientations available.

I am able to make the lock work in the manifest file but this is a global setting and I would prefer not to have to build 2 APK files to distribute, one for each device size.

Is this at all possible in the manifest file or do I need to add some code. If so where and what :-)

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your MainActivity, capture what is the screen resolution using below code

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels; //240
int height = dm.heightPixels; //320
```

Then make a conditional statement for small screen and inside the condition add the below codes as you desire

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

OR

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Thanks very much this did the job!!! I needed to import the android.util.DisplayMetrics and android.content.pm.ActivityInfo into the app but after that this worked.  Thanks again